# Game Development in android using framework?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Among the following framework which one is best one for developing game application in android?

1)Libgdx

2)andengine

3) rokon

4) catcake

5)loon-simple

6) jmonkeyengine

or else native development is better without using any frameworks.

I am new to game development. My requirement to to create a building blocks game. I don`t know where to start. If any one knows means help me out

Comment: What type of game are you building, this might determine the framework you should use.

Comment: similar to building blocks games.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android game engine for 2d and 3d games?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227759/android-game-engine-for-2d-and-3d-games)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would hand tailor everything (immensely satisfying and likely to perform better). By using these frameworks you become dependant on them so if you do go down that route I suggest choosing one that is frequently updated (as Android is) and likely to stick around.

If you want to be **cool** you could build the game in [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html).

Did this in a hackathon: https://github.com/cjami/Bubble-Pops/

Good luck!